# How to find the range of the given function?

Tags: calculus, functions

> Find the range of $$f(x)=\dfrac{x^2+14x+9}{x^2+2x+3}$$ where $x\in \mathbb R$

I thought of finding derivative but this will get too complicated so i am completely blank.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try to simplify it a bit first by completing squares: $f(x) =1 + \frac{12x+6}{(x+1)^2 + 2}$. If you consider $g(x) = f(x-1) = 1 + \frac{12x-6}{x^2+2}$ instead then it might be easier to compute the derivatives and solve $g'(x) = 0$.

Comment: But why solving $g'(x)=0$ will give me range, what is reason?

Comment: $f$ and $g$ have the same range so you can work with this if you find that to be easier. Solving $g'(x) = 0$ gives you the values of $x$ for which the maximum/minimum is. Since the function is continuous the intermediate value theorem says that any value between the min and the max is taken by the function. This will allow you to determine the range.

Comment: Can I generalise this method for all rational function like this? (*method given in my book stinks a lot*)

Comment: One can make it into a fairly general method: The first thing to check is if the function is defined for all $x$ (that the denominator is not zero). This is the case here. Then determine the asymptotic values as $x\to\pm\infty$. Finally you can compute $f'(x) = 0$ to determine local max/min points and combine this with the previous information to extract what the range is.

Comment: @winther i don't see the role of asymptotic values, is it used for intermediate value theorem

Comment: I wrote up some notes on some general steps needed to determine the range in an answer below. The asymptotic values is needed since if they are $\pm\infty$ then the range will extend out to $\pm\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some general notes on finding the range for a rational function:

First of all a rational function is continuous where it's defined so if $y_1$ and $y_2$ is in the range then so is any value inbetween $y_1$ and $y_2$ (the intermediate value theorem). This is a key fact needed to determine the range.

First we check that the denominator is not zero. If the denominator has a zero at $x=x_*$ then $\lim_{x\to x_*}|f(x)| = \infty$ so the range will extend to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ (or both). You can determine this by computing the one-sided limits $\lim_{x\to x_*^{\pm}} f(x)$. For your function we have $x^2+2x+3 = (x+1)^2+2 \geq 2$ so this is not the case here.

Next we determine the asymptotic values by computing $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x)$. Again if one or both of these limits are $\pm\infty$ then the range will exend out to these values. For your case these limits are $1$ and togeather with the previous information we can conclude that the function is bounded.

In after any of the steps above if the range has beens shown to be $\mathbb{R}$ then we can stop. But if this is not the case then there is one more step needed. We need to determine the local max/min values of the function. This is done by solving $f'(x) = 0$ and computing $f(x)$ using the values found. For your function we find the extremal points $x=-2$ and $x=1$ and $f(-2) = -5$ and $f(1) = 4$. The point $x=-2$ is a global minimum and $x=1$ is a global maximum.

Combinding all the information found by going through the steps above you should be able to determine the range quite easily. For your function it's not hard to see that the range is $[-5,4]$. For this last step it's often quite useful to draw a sketch based on the information previously found. For example I drew up this rough sketch:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd have to find the derivative for this problem. But don't worry, finding the derivative is not as cumbersome as you think. Just use the quotient rule and you'll get something reasonable.

You should get $-\frac{12(x^2+x-2)}{(x^2+2x+3)^2}$ and setting that equal to 0 and solving for $x$ should be straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Its not that hard to differentiate.

$\frac {d}{dx} \dfrac {x^2 + 14x + 9}{x^2 + 2x + 3} = 0\\
\dfrac {(x^2 + 2x + 3)(2x + 14) - (2x + 2)(x^2 + 14x + 9)}{(x^2 + 2x + 3)^2} = 0$

Since the denominator is clearly not $0.$  We can multiply through by the denominator.

$2x^3 + 4x^2 + 6x + 14x^2 + 28x + 42 - 2x^3 - 2x^2 - 28x^2 - 28x -18x - 18 = 0\\-12 x^2 -12x +24=0\\
-12 (x+2)(x-1) = 0$

And that gives you your local minimum and maximum.

Next show that these are absolute max and min, too.

$ f(-2) <\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} f(x) <f(1)$ and $f(-2)<\lim_\limits{x\to-\infty}f(x) < f(1)$

$[f(-2), f(1)]$

Comment: Can you tell me what this step does "Next show that these are absolut max and min, too."

Comment: Suppose  you had $f(x) = x^3 - x.$  If you found the local max and min, those would not be the absolute max and min.  You need to prove that the local max is the absolute max and the local min is the absolute min.  Show that f(x) never passes above or below the identified points.  Since the function is continuous everywhere and there are no other critical points (derivative = 0 or undefined) then you just need to look at the extremes.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = 1$, the maximum value of $f$'s range is the maximum value of $f$, and similarly for the minimum value (unless of course, it were asymptotic -- think exponentials).

Do you know how to find the extrema of functions?

Comment: Yes i know to find

Comment: Then you have the tools to solve it!

Answer (score 1):

A simpler (pre-calculus) solution. Let we consider the equation $f(x)=k$:
$$\frac{x^2+14x+9}{x^2+2x+3}=k\tag{1}$$
that is equivalent to:
$$ (1-k) x^2 +(14-2k) x + (9-3k) = 0 \tag{2} $$
whose discriminant equals:
$$ \Delta = (14-2k)^2-4(1-k)(9-3k) = 8(k+5)(k-4).\tag{3}$$
Such discriminant vanishes at the boundary of $\text{range}(f)$, hence:

> $$\color{red}{ \text{range}(f) = [-5,4]}.\tag{4}$$

The endpoints are attained at $x=-2$ and $x=1$ by solving $(1)$ for $k=-5$ and $k=4$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(y-1)x^2+(2y-14)x+(3y-9)=0$$
$$\Delta=(2y-14)^2-4(y-1)(3y-9)=4(-2y^2-2y+40)$$
then
$$x=\frac{-(2y-14)\pm  2\sqrt{-2y^2-2y+40} }{2(y-1)}=\frac{7-y\pm  \sqrt{-2y^2-2y+40} }{y-1}$$
$$R_f=[-5,4]$$

Comment: 1 is in the range.